# Filter a dictionary with a list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where every key and every value is unique. I'd like to be able to filter based on a list of strings. I've seen lot of examples with the key is consistent but not where its unique like in the example below.

```
thisdict = { "brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964} 
filt = ["rand", "ar"]
```

result

```
{"brand": "Ford","year": 1964}
```

Comment: have you misspelled filt , filt = ["brand", "year"] or the filtering list can contain substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the key of the dict should be contained in any filter value. Accordingly, my solution looks like this:

```py
thisdict = { "brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964} 
filt = ["rand", "ar"]

def matches(filter, value):
    return any(x in value for x in filter)

def filter(dict, filt):
    return {k: v for k, v in dict.items() if matches(filt, k)}

print(filter(thisdict, filt))
```

**Output:**

```
{'brand': 'Ford', 'year': 1964}
```

---

Or shortened:

```py
thisdict = { "brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964} 
filt = ["rand", "ar"]

filtered = {k: v for k, v in thisdict.items() if any(x in k for x in filt)}

print(filtered)
```

**Output:**

```
{'brand': 'Ford', 'year': 1964}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `any()` function to search for partially matching keys.

```py
# use any to search strings in filt among keys in thisdict
{k:v for k,v in thisdict.items() if any(s in k for s in filt)}
# {'brand': 'Ford', 'year': 1964}
```